# Using a function to recall tuples

Tags: python

I have come across another problem that although the string inside the tuple has been found; only the first tuple of information is being returned.

```
def info(name, food_list):
    food_list = = [('Donut', '320', '4.00'), ('Apple Pie', '200', '3.20')]
    innertup = food_list[0]
    for c in food_list:
        if name in c:
            print name,':',innertup[1:3]
            return None
        else:
            print "Unknown food", name
            return None
```

When this is run it only prints out `Donut: ('320', '4.00')`, even when Apple Pie is the name in question the function returns `Apple Pie: ('200', '3.20')`. I'm also looking to get rid of the brackets surrounding the tuple and I'm not sure how, putting `str()` around it does not solve the problem.

Comment: You aren't including the function call. What arguments are you using to call the function with?

Comment: "even when Apple Pie is the name in question the function returns Apple Pie: ('200', '3.20')"
Did you mean "even when Apple Pie is the name in question the function returns Donut: ....)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def info(name, food_list):
    food_list = = [('Donut', '320', '4.00'), ('Apple Pie', '200', '3.20')]
    for c in food_list:
        if name in c:
            print c[0],':',c[1], ' ', c[2]
            return None
    else:
        print "Unknown food", name
        return None
```

c[0] will be the name of the food, c[1] the first number (possibly the quantity) and c[2] the second number (possibly the price).

Be carefull! The else statement is for the for loop, not for the if!

Comment: Thank you very much! As soon as I read over your code my mistake hit me like a truck haha.

Answer (score 0):

See if a name is in one of the tuples:

```
for x in food_list:
    if 'Apple Pie' in x:
        print (x)
```

Print the tuple in a [better format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
print "{0[0]}: {0[1]} : {0[2]}".format(x)
```

You can change the formatting around the `{}` pairs to match what you want.

So overall:

```
def info(name, food_list):
    for x in food_list:
        if name in x:
            print "{0[0]}: {0[1]} : {0[2]}".format(x)
```